# Find and count all in Sails.js + Waterline

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Is there a way to do select query and count_all query via single method?
For pagination purposes we need to know total number of items so we can calculate and show number of pages.

Answer (score 1):

```
getLength: function(req, res) {
    Posts.find({}).exec(function(err, items){

        return items.length;
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, but when doing pagination you usually set some criteria in find method like skip and limit so then items.length is not the total number of items in database.

Comment: You could filter the search query. check out this: http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Querylanguage.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Sails.Js - How I do pagination in sails.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648059/sails-js-how-i-do-pagination-in-sails-js) for pagination in Waterline.

To get the total number of items, you can use:

```
Post.count().exec(function (err, nbOfInstances) {
    if(err) return res.negociate(err);

    return res.ok(nbOfInstances);
});
```

Comment: Yes, but then I need to call Post.find().skip(10).limit(10).exec() { ... } to get posts for specific page and that is two method calls. My questions was is there some method that do both requests and returns specific posts collection and a number of total posts in db. What I want is one method with both informations so I have less coding.

Answer (score 1):

First you query and get data after that you delete limit, skip parameters and get count

```
delete query._criteria.limit;
delete query._criteria.skip;
Model.count(query._criteria).exec(function countCB(error, count) {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I also couldn't find any built-in method to do that in one request so I do it like this:

```
let queryParams = {},
    pageNo = 1,
    perPage = 10;
Post.count(queryParams)
    .then(_count=>{        
        return {posts_count: _count, 
               posts: Post.find(queryParams).paginate({page: pageNo, limit: perPage})};
     })
     .then(res.ok)
     .catch(err=>res.negotiate(err.message));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
/*
{
   posts_count: 0,
   posts: []
}

*/
```