# datatables server side pagination in sails js

Tags: pagination, datatables, sails.js

I am new to sails js.In my controller, I am calling an api which gives me a large set of data, approximately 10000 records. I want to show this data in my front end using the datatables, 100 records per page.I don't want all data to be fetched in a single call. Data for each page should be loaded using pagination. Do anyone have any idea? It will be of great help. I am not using the database directly. Everything is via API.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Comment: You can try .limit() and .skip() in your api at controller for pagination.

Comment: You can use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-datatable. works pretty fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sails.Js - How I do pagination in sails.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648059/sails-js-how-i-do-pagination-in-sails-js)

Answer (score -1):

See [Sails.Js - How I do pagination in sails.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648059/sails-js-how-i-do-pagination-in-sails-js):

In sails.js:

> `Model.find().paginate({page: 2, limit: 10});`
>
> `Model.find({ where: { name: 'foo' }, limit: 10, skip: 10 });`

(Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26653121/3340229)

In the frontend, you can add query parameters for this:

> `http://yourDomain.com/ModelName?skip=10&limit=10`

(Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27937261/3340229)

Comment: Instead of re-posting, close this topic by mark it as duplicate.

Comment: I didn't have the privilege to flag back then, I was just trying to help. Flagged as duplicate now.